# Cannot access jsp pages in web-inf folder even by using a servlet

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

My environment: Windows 7 64 bit, Eclipse Kepler, Glassfish 4.
My dynamic web project structure outline:

```
MyProject
|
|__java (src folder)
|    |
|    |__controller (package)
|         |
|         |__ControllerServlet.java
|    
|__WebContent
    |
    |__WEB-INF
         |
         |__view
              |__category.jsp        
              |
              |etc...
```

I enter the url `http://localhost:4848/AffableBean/category` into my browser, but it fails and gives me a 404 error.
Why does this happen ?

ControllerServlet.java: (snippet only)

```
@WebServlet(name = "ControllerServlet", urlPatterns = { "/category",
        "/addToCart", "/viewCart", "/updateCart", "/checkout", "/purchase",
        "/chooseLanguage" })
public class ControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String userPath = request.getServletPath();

        String url = "/WEB-INF/view" + userPath + ".jsp";
        System.out.println("test url = " + url);//TEST

        try {
            request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }       

//same code for doPost.
```

How do I fix this error ? I don't think any request is even hitting the controller servlet.

Comment: You have a valuable `System.out.println` call.  Does the output occur?  If so, what does it show?

Comment: @Brandon - When I enter the url http://localhost:4848/AffableBean/category, I don't see any output/printing on the console. 
I don't think this servlet is being reached. I wonder if I should use web.xml instead of annotations.

Comment: I solved the problem. When I would access the web app from the localhost:4848, it would take me to index.jsp.
I noticed that the url for the web app is `http://MyComputerName:6262/AffableBean/`. I added /category to that
to make it work. Server port number is 6262, and admin server port number is 4848. I don't really understand this.
I never faced this thing when I used tomcat. There was only port number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. When I would access the web app from the localhost:4848, it would take me to index.jsp. I noticed that the url for the web app is `http://MyComputerName:6262/AffableBean/`. I added /category to that to make it work. Server port number is 6262, and admin server port number is 4848. I don't really understand this. I never faced this thing when I used tomcat. There was only port number.